# Watching controller variables, which are set to this instead of $scope, possible? Bad Idea

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am struggling with the concept of `this` in angular. I've been reading the differences as explained very well in ['this' vs $scope in AngularJS controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605917/this-vs-scope-in-angularjs-controllers)
but I have still issues whether this is useful in many cases at all.

I created a controller and a `this.the_value` var

```
angular.module("TheApp", [])
    .controller("TheCtrl", ["$scope", function($scope){
         this.the_value = "Init value";
}]);
```

Now I like the concept here as I can write `ng-controller="TheCtrl as myCtrl"` and reference the value in the view by `myCtrl.the_value`. 
I separate contexts when dealing with nested controllers, that's fine.

Then I realized I need to watch this variable via `$scope.$watch`.

Now I either have to rewrite all my view code and move the_value to `$scope` instead of `this` so I can use

```
 $scope.$watch("the_value", function(newValue, old ){
        console.log("The old value: '"+old+"', the new value: '"+newValue+"'");
    });
```

or do some nasty things like

```
   $scope.$watch("myCtrl.the_value", function(newValue, old ){
        console.log("This: The old value: '"+old+"', the new value: '"+newValue+"'");
    });
```

which is evil as I am creating a dependency on my view alias of the controller name. If I refactor the view alias, this will break. (Even unit testing will get dirty with this dependency)

Does `this` has a very very limited use, or am I getting something wrong? Everywhere where I initially started using `this` turned into `$scope` when I was adding new behaviour to the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using this, you can watch first level variables passing a function as first parameter to $scope.$watch

```
$scope.watch(

  function() {
    return this.the_value; //this is the real variable to be watched
  }.bind(this), //binding allows to use 'this' inside function

  function(newVal, oldVal) {
    console.log(newVal, oldVal); //this is the callback
  }

);
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy fix for this is to watch a function that returns the variable observed.

Wrapping the variable will allow you to use this and not require you to use the controllerAs alias.

```js
$scope.$watch(function() {
  return that.the_value

}, function(newValue, old) {
  console.log("This: The old value: '" + old + "', the new value: '" + newValue + "'");
});
```

Comment: @tarini posted the correct answer. You have a typo, you are using that instead of this but even with that a proper bind is necessary in order for the example to work.

Comment: I had declared var that=this to avoid any closure issues.